# How do I save a variable between executions of ruby from vim?

Tags: ruby, vim, vim-plugin

With pre-1.9 versions of Ruby, I was able to do something like the following in Vim.

```
:ruby foo = "bar"
:ruby print foo
```

This now gives me a NameError because `foo` isn't defined.

How do I "save" a variable between executions of `:ruby`? In particular I want to be able to use this functionality from a Vim plugin and store an object (as opposed to a primitive value like a string or number, which could be achieved by storing it in a Vim variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty way to do this is to prefix your variable name with a `$`, which will make it act like a global variable.

```
:ruby $foo = "bar"
:ruby print $foo
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always store the value in a *Vim* variable:

```
:ruby VIM::command('let foo = "bar"')
:ruby print VIM::evaluate('foo')
```

Comment: Thanks. This won't work for objects though, will it? For example `foo = Bar.new`?

Comment: No, it won't, just for primitive payloads. There should be a Ruby solution (somethink like a Singleton), too, but I don't know enough Ruby (and details of the Vim integration) to help. Hopefully someone else has an idea.